# Dictionary Manupilation

Tags: python

We represent scores of batsmen across a sequence of matches in a two level dictionary as follows:

{'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}

Each match is identified by a string, as is each player.  The scores are all integers.  The names associated with the matches are not fixed (here they are 'match1','match2','match3'), nor are the names of the players.  A player need not have a score recorded in all matches

Define a Python function "orangecap(d)" that reads a dictionary d of this form and identifies the player with the highest total score.  Your function should return a pair (playername,topscore) where playername is a string, the name of the player with the highest score, and topscore is an integer, the total score of playername.

The input will be such that there are never any ties for highest total score.

For instance:

> > > orangecap({'match1':{'player1':57, 'player2':38}, 'match2':{'player3':9, 'player1':42}, 'match3':{'player2':41, 'player4':63, 'player3':91}})
> > >       ('player3', 100)
> > >
> > > orangecap({'test1':{'Ashwin':84, 'Kohli':120}, 'test2':{'ashwin':59, 'Pujara':42}})
> > >       ('Kohli', 120)

This is my code:

```
def orangecap(d):
s=[]
t=[]
for i in sorted(d.keys()):
    for j in sorted(d[i].keys()):
        flag=0
        for k in range(len(s)):
            if(s[k]==j):
                t[k:k]+=[d[i][j]]
                flag=1
                break
        if(flag==0):
            s.append(j)
            t.append(d[i][j])

m=max(t)
for i in range(len(t)):
    if t[i]==m:
        return (s[i],m)
```

Comment: @JohnConde After trying a lot only, I am asking for help since I am new to Python

Comment: You forgot to ask a question...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to operate on nested dictionary in python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42444903/how-to-operate-on-nested-dictionary-in-python-3-x)

Answer (score 0):

You didn't quite get a question out there, in future try be specific in what you are asking or try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for general pointers etc.

First to note in python, as in all programming languages try to be as expressive as possible when naming variables, it will make it much easier for everyone (most often yourself) to work out what is going on (and wrong).

So in the question we are trying to work out the total scores for each player. In other words we are combining  the dictionary for each match into a single dictionary, adding if we have a duplicate key. So

```
def orangecap(d):

    # Make a new dict to count the totals

    totals = {}

    # Loop over every players score in every match.

    for match in d.values():
        for player in match:

            # Check if player is in totals dictionary. If not add them.

            if player not in totals:
                totals[player] = 0

            # Add players score in this match to there total score.

            totals[player] += match[player]

    #initialise highest_total as we will use it later for comparison.

    highest_total = -1

    #loop through totals to find highest score

    for player in totals:

        # if players score is greater than current highest, set highest_player
        # to be current player, and set the highest total to players total

        if totals[player] >  highest_total:
            highest_player = player
            highest_total = totals[player]

    # return the highest player and highest total

    return highest_player, highest_total
```